# Number of positive integers $\le n$ which are a multiple of $p$

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

I was trying to understand the proof of the following formula:

$$ \varphi(n)= n\prod_{\substack{p \text{ prime }\ p \vert n}} \left( 1- \frac{1}{p}\right) $$

Using inclusion-exclusion.

What we want is the number of positive elements $\le$ that are coprime to $n$, Suppose  $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{e_{i}}$ is the unique prime factsization of $n$ and let let $A_i$ be the set  of such positive integers that $i$ prime number does not divide them with $1\le i\le k$ and the primes are all a factor of $n$,then we want $$\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} \left|A_{i}\right|$$

But here we need to know the number of positive integers $\le n$ which are a multiple of $p$,this is given by $$\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \rfloor$$
Where $\lfloor  \rfloor$ denoted the floor function.

But how one can show
that?

Comment: Prove *what*? Note that the floor function is not needed since $n/p$ is an integer.

Comment: The multiples of $p\le n$ are $1p,2p,3p......,kp=n$ .  Is in not obvious that there are $k = \frac np$ of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's assumed to be obvious and self explanitory.

The multiples of $p \le n$ are $1p, 2p, 3p, ....., kp\le n$ for some $k$.  That means that there $k$  such multiples and $kp \le n < (k+1)p$.  So $k \le \frac pn < k+1$.

So $k = \lfloor \frac np \rfloor$.

Comment: Um.... because we *choose* $kp$ by definition to be the last multiple of $p$ less than or equal to $n$.  If you list the multiples they go from $1p$ to....... $something\times p$.  That something is the number of multiples.  If there were any more then $something\times p$ wouldn't be the last multiple of $p$.

Comment: If $kp$ is the *last* multiple of $p$ less or equal to $n$, the $(k+1)p$ can't be less than or equal to $n$ because $kp$ *was* the last such multiple.

Comment: Where you write $\lfloor \frac{p}{n} \rfloor$ don't you mean  $\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \rfloor$? For $p<n$, isn't $\lfloor \frac{p}{n} \rfloor =0$?

Comment: Of course I do.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach is somewhat defective because it makes no attempt to address the OP's question(s), which other reactions have done.  Further this approach is **intuitive** only, with the formality of math all but discarded.

To prove (informally - via intuition only):

$$\varphi(n) = n \times \prod_{p ~\text{prime}~ p|n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$

Each prime # is relatively prime to all the others.  Very informally, one can construe divisibility by one prime # to be an **independent** event with respect to divisibility by another prime #.

For example, in the set $\{1,2,\cdots, 100\}$ 
the chance that a random # from this set is divisible by 2 is $\frac{1}{2}.$  
If you restrict the set, and only consider those #'s that are 
multiples of 5 (i.e. $\{5, 10, \cdots, 100\}$), then the chance 
that a random # from this subset is (also) divisible by 2 is 
(still) $\frac{1}{2}.$

Extending the analogy, the chance that a random # from the
set $\{2,4,\cdots, 100\}$ is relatively prime to $5$ is $\frac{4}{5}.$

**Note**: this intuition critically depends on the fact that $100$ is a common multiple of $2$ and $5$.

Let $U \equiv \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}.$ 
Let $P \equiv \{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_k\}$ be the complete list 
of all distinct primes that divide $n$.

Let $E_p ~: p \in P$ denote the event that a given random # in $U$ is relatively prime to $p$. 
Then chance of event $E_p$ occurring is
$\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$

In order for any # $u \in U$ to be relatively prime to $n$, 
it must be
relatively prime to each $p \in P$.

Since (**intuitively**) $E_{p_1}, E_{p_2}, \cdots, E_{p_k}$ are all
independent events, the chance that a # chosen at random from $U$ will be relatively prime to $n$ is therefore,

$$\prod_{p ~\text{prime}~ p|n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$

Since $U$ contains exactly $n$ numbers, the formula is **intuitively** justified.

---

**Addendum** 
After some time, I became bothered by the informality of my approach, and tried to formalize it into a proof.  After a few hours, I decided to research the problem for insights.

I actually found the proof handed to me, as a result of the ideas mentioned at 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function $~~~$ and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

These articles really left me nothing to prove, so I can at least summarize the ideas. From what I read, it seems like there are only two ways of proving it.

One way is to use the inclusion exclusion principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  I prefer to avoid this approach.

The alternative  approach is described below.

---

$\underline{\text{General Terminology}}$

If $V$ is any set with a finite # of elements, 
let $|V|$ denote the number of elements in $V$.

For any positive integer $k > 1$, let $A_k$ denote the set $\{0, 1, 2, \cdots, (k-1)\}.$

For any positive integer $k > 1$, let $\overline{A_k}$ denote the set $\{i ~: i \in A_k, ~i ~\text{relatively prime to} ~k\}.$

$\underline{\text{The Chinese Remainder Theorem}}$

Let $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k$ each be a positive integer $> 1$ 
where these $k$ integers are all **pairwise** coprime.

Let $N = \prod_{i=1}^k n_i.$

Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k$ be any integers such that 
$a_1 \in A_{n_1}, a_2 \in A_{n_2}, \cdots, a_k \in A_{n_k}$.

Then the following system of $k$ congruency equations will have **exactly** one solution in $A_N$:

$\displaystyle ~~~~~~~~x \equiv a_1 \pmod{n_1}$ 
$\displaystyle ~~~~~~~~x \equiv a_2 \pmod{n_2}$ 
$\displaystyle ~~~~~~~~~~~ \cdots$ 
$\displaystyle ~~~~~~~~x \equiv a_k \pmod{n_k}$

In my opinion, the corresponding wikipedia page cited above proves this result.

The remainder of the proof will only need the special case of
the Chinese Remainder Theorem where $k=2.$

---

$\underline{\text{To prove:}}$

Given, that $m,n$ are relatively prime positive integers, each $> 1.$
Then $\varphi(m \times n) = [\varphi (m)] \times [\varphi (n)].$

---

$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$

Let $F ~: ~\left(A_m \times A_n\right) \to A_{(mn)}$ be specified as follows:

Given $~a \in A_m, ~b \in A_n,~$ by the Chinese Remainer Theorem, 
there exists a unique $x \in A_{(mn)}$ 
such that $~x \equiv a \pmod{m} ~\text{and} ~x \equiv b \pmod{n}.$ 
Then $F(a,b) = x.$

Suppose that $F(a_1, b_1) = x = F(a_2, b_2).$ 
Then, $~\{a_1 \equiv x \equiv a_2 \pmod{m} 
~\text{and} ~b_1 \equiv x \equiv b_2 \pmod{n}\} ~\Rightarrow$
$\{a_1 = a_2 ~\text{and} ~b_1 = b_2\}.~$ Thus $F$ is an injection.

Therefore, since $|A_{(mn)}| = |A_m| \times |A_n|,~$ $F$ is also a
surjection.  Therefore, $F$ is a bijection.

Since $~\varphi(mn) = |\overline{A_{(mn)}}|, ~\varphi(m) = |\overline{A_m}|,
~\text{and} ~\varphi(n) = |\overline{A_n}|,$ 
it remains to show that $|\overline{A_{(mn)}}| = |\overline{A_m}| \times |\overline{A_n}|.$

If $~a \in \overline{A_m}, ~b \in \overline{A_n} ~\text{and} ~F(a,b) = x,$ 
then $~\{x \equiv a \pmod{m} ~\text{and} ~x \equiv b \pmod{n}\} ~\Rightarrow$ 
$\{x ~\text{is relatively prime to both} ~m ~\text{and} ~n\} ~\Rightarrow$ 
$x ~\text{is relatively prime to} ~(mn) ~\Rightarrow ~x \in \overline{A_{(mn)}}.$

Conversely, if $~F(a,b) = x~$ and $~x \in \overline{A_{(mn)}}$ 
then $~\{x ~\text{is relatively prime to} ~(mn)\} ~\Rightarrow$ 
$\{x ~\text{is relatively prime to both} ~m ~\text{and} ~n\}.$ 
Further $~x \equiv a \pmod{m}~$ and $~x \equiv b \pmod{n}.~$ 
Therefore, $~a \in \overline{A_m}~$ and $~b \in \overline{A_n}.$

Thus, if $G$ is the same map as $F$ but with its domain restricted to
$\left(\overline{A_m} \times \overline{A_n}\right)$ 
then $\{$the range of $~G\} \subseteq \overline{A_{(mn)}}~$
and $\overline{A_{(mn)}} \subseteq~$
$\{$the range of $~G\}.$ 
Therefore, $\{$the range of $~G\} = \overline{A_{(mn)}}.$ 
Therefore, if $~G$ is regarded as a map from
$~\left(\overline{A_m} \times \overline{A_n}\right) \to \overline{A_{(mn)}}$ 
then $G$ is a surjection onto $\overline{A_{(mn)}}$.

Further, the property of $G$ being an injection is inherited from $F$. 
Therefore, $~G$ is a bijection from
$~\left(\overline{A_m} \times \overline{A_n}\right) \to \overline{A_{(mn)}}.$ 
Therefore, $|\overline{A_{(mn)}}| = |\overline{A_m}| \times |\overline{A_n}|.$

---

$\underline{\text{To prove:}}$

$$\varphi(n) = n \times \prod_{p ~\text{prime}~ p|n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$

---

$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$

Let the prime factorization of $n$ be given by

$$ \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{(\alpha_i)}.$$

The proof will be by induction on $k$.

For $j \in \{1,2,\cdots, k\},$

let $\displaystyle r_j = \prod_{i=1}^j p_i^{(\alpha_i)}~$ and

let $\displaystyle s_j = \prod_{i=1}^j \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_i}\right).$

Thus, $~r_1 = p_1^{\alpha_1}, ~r_k = n,~$ and the problem reduces to showing 
that for all $~j \in \{1,2,\cdots, k\}, \varphi(r_j) = r_j \times s_j.$

In the "Value for a prime power argument" section of
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function
it is proven that for any prime $p$ and positive integer $\alpha$,

$$\varphi\left(p^{\alpha}\right) = p^{\alpha} \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$

Therefore, it is immediate that $\varphi(r_1) = r_1 \times s_1.$

Inductively assume that for one specific $J \in \{1,2,\cdots (k-1)\},$

$\varphi\left(r_j\right) = r_j \times s_j.$

Then:

- from the definition, $r_{(J)}$ is relatively prime to $[p_{(J+1)}]^{\alpha_{(J+1)}}$
- $\displaystyle 
  \varphi\left\{[p_{(J+1)}]^{\alpha_{(J+1)}}\right\} 
  = \left\{[p_{(J+1)}]^{\alpha_{(J+1)}}\right\} \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_{(J+1)}}\right).$
- From the previous analysis,
  [re $\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m) \times \varphi(n)$] 
   
  $\displaystyle \varphi\left[r_{(J+1)}\right] = [r_j \times s_j] \times
  \left\{[p_{(J+1)}]^{\alpha_{(J+1)}}\right\} \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_{(J+1)}}\right)$
- $= r_{(J+1)} \times s_{(J+1)}.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence

$$p, 2p, 3p, \dots, pk$$

This is an AP with initial term $p$ and common difference $p$.

The $k$<sup>th</sup> term is given by $pk$.

We want $pk \le n$.

$\therefore, k \le {n \over p} \implies k = \lfloor {n \over p} \rfloor$