# The formula to calculate Euler Phi function

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I know that $$\phi(m)=m\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\text{  Where }m=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}$$

But when i tried to find a formula of $\phi(n)$ i got this:
$$\phi(m)=\phi \left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \phi(p_i^{a_i}) $$ Now since $\phi(p^m)=p^m -p^{m-1}$, Thus:
$$\phi(m)=\prod_{i=1}^n \left(p_i^{a_i}-p_i^{a_i-1}\right )$$

Is this’s a valid proof? and if it is why most people are using this formula:
$$\phi(m)=m\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right) $$
**Side note:**

I’ve used the same method to find the formula of $\sigma(n)$ and $\sigma_m(n)$

Comment: Are you sure that you know the multiplicativity of the function beforehand?

Comment: Yes if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ Then $\phi(mn) =  \phi(m)\phi(n)$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858851/number-of-positive-integers-le-n-which-are-a-multiple-of-p/3858930?r=SearchResults&s=2|6.1777#3858930), **especially its Addendum**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is valid (assuming you already proved the facts you used about $\phi$). Both formulas are practically equivalent

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (p_i^{a_i}-p_i^{a_i-1} ) =\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right) = m \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right) $$

and both are widely used.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth writing this as $\phi(n)=n\prod_{p\in\Bbb P,\,p|n}(1-1/p)$. Your proof is the standard one, viz.$$\begin{align}\phi(n)&=\prod_{p\in\Bbb P,\,p|n}\phi(p^{\operatorname{ord}_p(n)})\\&=\prod_{p\in\Bbb P,\,p|n}p^{\operatorname{ord}_p(n)}(1-1/p)\\&=\prod_{p\in\Bbb P,\,p|n}p^{\operatorname{ord}_p(n)}\prod_{p\in\Bbb P,\,p|n}(1-1/p)\\&=n\prod_{p\in\Bbb P,\,p|n}(1-1/p).\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you might be confusing $\operatorname{ord}_p(n)$ with $v_p(n)$. As far as I know, $\operatorname{ord}_p(a)$ is used to denote the smallest number $k$ such that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.